# Docker: one shared image or separate image for each service?

Tags: performance, docker, memory-management, docker-compose, docker-image

I want to figure out the most efficient way (memory and space) to run multiple 
services with complicated dependencies.

Suppose, we have a project with 3 services:

- service S1 only uses libraries A and B
- service S2 only uses libraries B and C
- service S3 only uses libraries A and C

So, if you create a separate image for each of these, you will end up with this structure:

- S1

  - alpine layer
  - A and B libraries
- S2

  - alpine layer
  - B and C libraries
- S3

  - alpine layer
  - A and C libraries

Library layers do not share any files (though actually share libraries).

What is the best strategy to share the resources? Is it okay to use one image for all 3 services? (Store libraries A, B, C in one image layer)

**Upd**
We run all the services on one machine, not on a cluster
**Upd 2**
Here is an [example](https://github.com/grihabor/explore-docker-images/blob/master/README.md) (Spoiler: layers are not shared)

Answer (score 0):

If you are following a mircroservice oriented architecture, then each service should have its own image. Docker images are cheap, but if you have 1 bulky image and use that in all the services, that would not be ideal.

Also, that way you wont have dependencies with other services if you want to upgrade service specific libraries.

Comment: I'm talking about efficiency, not architecture style. What do you mean by 'not ideal'? I understand, that Docker image should be as small as possible, but here I want to use space and memory as little as possible.   
  
Of course, if we run our services on a cluster, it's not efficient, because we have to store a copy of layers we don't even use.